# ActionScript 3: How do curry functions work?

Tags: function, actionscript, currying

I just recently started looking at ActionScript code (as in, I literally just found out ActionScript was a thing yesterday). My only experience is with Java, so I have no idea how this code works:

```
public static function curry(func:Function,...args):Function
{
    return function (...args2):*{
        return func.apply(null,args.concat(args2));
    };
}
```

I don't understand what the asterisk is doing, where ...args2 came from (or what it is), or how you can have a return statement in a return statement. What would the equivalent Java code be? (Even if it's rather convoluted, I would probably be able to understand it a lot better.)

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript shares many similarities with JavaScript - but also provides a static types system as it is used in Java. What Java lacks is support for higher order functions. Functions, which accept functions as arguments or return functions or both.

`curry` accepts and arguments of type `Function` and an arbitrary number of additional arguments (the `...` rest parameter). It returns a `Function` which takes also takes an arbitrary number of arguments. When this function is called, all arguments are concatenated and applied to the initial function.

```
// pseudo code
const f:Function = curry(function(o):* { o.join(', '); }, 1, 2, 3);
const result:* = f(4, 5, 6);
trace(result); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

In Java, inner classes would be used or the lambda expressions introduces with Java 8.